# How to overwrite an echo/printf line with another one? (Making it start at the center of the screen)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script

I want to write a script which outputs sentences I choose. I want them to appear in the center of the screen: output the first one, and then make the second one appear over the first. Here's my code:

```
    COLUMNS=$(tput cols) 

printf "%*s\n" $((($COLUMNS)/2)) "Hey, welcome to my script!" "%\r"
sleep 2
printf "%*s" $((($COLUMNS)/2)) "This is a new line!"
```

My intention is to overwrite the first line with the second, in the same way as `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl` does at the beginning of their particular Star Wars version. I managed to make them appear at the center by reading another question, but I find impossible to make the second line start at the very same line of the first. Any clues?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `c`

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm sorry. I thought adding a C tag would help more people to see my question, as I thought bash printf worked similarly as C's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `\n` in your first `printf`.  That makes the cursor move to the next line, so when you print the new text it is not on the same line to overwrite the old text.  If you remove that you should be good:

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols) 

printf "%*s\r" $((COLUMNS/2)) "Hey, welcome to my script!"
sleep 2
printf "%*s" $((COLUMNS/2)) "This is a new line!"
printf "\n"
```

I fixed up your correct observation about the `\r` being wrong, and simplified the math a little.  Then I added a last `\n` to get the prompt onto its own line at the end

Comment: That returned me an error, (line 12: printf: %\r: invalid number), but using your previous comment as a reference I managed to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: @xvlaze Sorry about that, I updated my answer with a fix for that and a minor simplification to the arithmetic part

Comment: Works perfectly. Much cleaner!